GPU running out of memory for ConvLSTM model in Pytorch
I'm trying to replicate the bidirectional convolutional LSTM proposed in Xiong et al. 2017 to predict crowd count density maps, but I'm running into memory issues during the training. This is what I've done so far:

I adapted the ConvLSTM implementation by ndrplz and training on video clips.
using only 1 layer with a hidden dimension (number of filters) of 64
Batch dimensions are: (1, 25, 3, 480, 640). Where batch size = 1, frames per clip = 25, and (3, 480, 640) is the dimension for a single RGB frame.
Training on a RTX A4000 with 16GB VRAM

The paper's architecture actually uses 4 ConvLSTM layers with 128, 64, 64, 64 hidden states, respectively. So it's significantly more complex than my simple test model (1 ConvLSTM layer with 64 hidden states).
So far I've tried using auto mixed precision, and cropping the videos to a lower dimension. The paper doesn't say the GPU used for training, but it seems unrealistic for them to have used a super high memory GPU compared to what I'm using.
Does anyone have any ideas as to why I'm running out of memory so quickly? Are there any tips or suggestions for how to fix it? I believe it has to do with how several intermediate tensors are stored in memory for backpropagation. The number of parameters is 639224 which doesn't seem like too much to cause this memory issue.
